# How to add a new method to Ext Core?

Tags: javascript, extjs

Could you please tell how to add a new method to Ext Core:

```
Ext.get('id').myMethod();
```

It doesn't work:

```
Ext.extend(Ext.Element, {
    myMethod: function() {
        this.on('click', function() {
             alert(this);
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Assuming you are using ExtJS 3)

No, that's not the right way. We use `extend` when we need to extend a Class and create our own class.

Then if you would like to add additional functionalities or override some of the core methods, use `Ext.override`. This action is permanent and destructive since you can override any defined methods. We use `override` when we want to apply personal fixes or global changes (like overriding `Ext.form.Field` so to provide global, usable and cross `fields` functionalities).

For your case, it seems like you want to apply this method to all the elements you have captured from `Ext.get`. You will just need to override `Ext.Element`.

```
Ext.override(Ext.Element, {
    myMethod: function() {
         this.on('click', function() {
              alert(this);
         });
    }
});
```

An working example is given here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chaoszcat/2vvNX/1/).

*Note that `Ext.get` is giving you `Ext.Element` on a successful call. If you would like to create a customized `Ext.Element`, be sure to modify `Ext.get` so it will return your own customized `Ext.Element`, or provides your own customized function to get elements.*

Cheers!

Comment: Are there any differences in the addition of a new method to ExtJS 4?

Comment: Should work. They do have `Ext.override` and is not deprecated.